# How to read params from file to Schedule annotation in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-el

I create file init.txt in c:\Temp folder.

```
login=rtyhjmdsf
password=cxzxdrfks
fixrate=6000
```

How to read params 'fixrate' from my file to Schedule annotation in Spring ?
How to convert string to Long in SpEL ?

this constraction do not work (

```
@Component
@PropertySource("file:c:\temp\init.txt")
class CronSchedule {

@Scheduled(fixedRate = "#{Long(scheduler[fixrate])}" as Long)
fun publicImage() {
        println("I'm starting.")
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to convert it to long, instead fixedRateString can be used.

```
@Scheduled(fixedRateString = "${fixrate}")
```

Below code works in Java

```
@Component
@PropertySource("file:/tmp/init.txt")
class CronSchedule {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CronSchedule.class);

    private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

    @Scheduled(fixedRateString = "${fixrate}")
    public void reportCurrentTime() {
        log.info("The time is now {}", dateFormat.format(new Date()));
    }
}
```

Comment: That is great, thx. For kotlin @Scheduled(fixedRateString = "\${fixrate}")